# AngularJS - How to test if a function is called from within another function?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to get started with karma-jasmine and I'm wondering why this test fails:

```
it("should call fakeFunction", function() {
    spyOn(controller, 'addNew');
    spyOn(controller, 'fakeFunction');
    controller.addNew();
    expect(controller.fakeFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

In my controller that I've previously set up for this test I have the following:

```
function addNew() {
    fakeFunction(3);
}

function fakeFunction(number) {
    return number;
}
```

both `addNew` and `fakeFunction` are exposed using:

```
vm.addNew = addNew;
vm.fakeFunction = fakeFunction;
```

The test, however, fails with the following:

`Expected spy fakeFunction to have been called.`

I can make the test pass if I call the function from within my test. I was hoping, however, I could test if `fakeFunction` was called by another function.  What is the proper way to achieve this?

Update:

```
//test.js

beforeEach(function() {

    module("app");

    inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller) {

        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        controller = $controller("CreateInvoiceController", {$scope: $scope});

    });

});
```

If I test something like:

```
it('should say hello', function() {
    expect(controller.message).toBe('Hello');
});
```

The test passes if I put the following in my controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.message = 'Hello';
```

I just want to know how I can test if a public function was called from another function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `addNew` method is calling `fakeFunction`. However, it is not calling `controller.fakeFunction`, which is what your expectation is.

You'll need to change your code to use your controller, rather than these independent functions.

**EDIT**: You also need to not spy on your `addNew` function. This is causing the function to be replaced with a spy. The other alternative is to change it to:

```
spyOn(controller, 'addNew').and.callThrough()
```

Comment: I've tried calling `vm.fakeFunction` and it does not work either.  How exactly is it done?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I don't know what `vm` is, but that's not what you're testing, you're testing that `controller.fakeFunction` was called

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying.  `vm` is a common variable for capturing `this` in Angular controllers. In effect, `vm` and `controller` should both be referring to `this`.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah maybe you can post more code, how is your `controller` variable in the test set up for example? What does your controller look like?

Comment: vm is short name for ViewModel. usually use as `var vm = this;`

Comment: What if you're in a NodeJS context and have a bunch of exported functions outside of a class (so there's no `controller`)? Using `module.exports.exportedFunction` works but then I lose all the typing information for the function. Do you know of a better way?

Answer (score 10):

I just came across this problem myself. The previous answer by @Vadim has the right principles but I don't think everything was very clear. In my case, I am trying to call a public function on a service from within another function. Here are the relevant snippets:

Service:

```js
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', function() {

    function doSomething() {
      service.publicMethod();
    }

    function publicMethod(){
      // Do stuff
    }

    var service = {
      publicMethod: publicMethod
    };

    return service;
});
```

Test:

```js
it('calls the public method when doing something', function(){
  spyOn(service, 'publicMethod');

  // Run stuff to trigger doSomething()

  expect(service.publicMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The key here is that the function being tested needs to be calling the same reference as the public function that is being spy'd on.