# Spy on a function which is called by another function in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

How do I spy on a function which is called by another function in [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/)?

The expectation is true if I call `this.bar()` but I'm not interested on that.

**Spec**

```
import * as src from './src;

describe('app', () => {
  it('should call bar', () => {
    spyOn(src, 'bar');
    src.foo();
    expect(src.bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**Source**

```
function foo() {
  bar();
}

function bar() {
  console.log('bar');
}

export {
  foo,
  bar,
};
```

Comment: what version of jasmine are you using?

Comment: @leobelizquierdo version 2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

In Jasmine, when you use `spyOn`, it mocks that function and doesn't execute anything. If you want to test further function calls within, you need to call [`and.callThrough()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>and.stub</code>) as below, please try it

```
spyOn(src, 'bar').and.callThrough();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: [AngularJS - How to test if a function is called from within another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822947/angularjs-how-to-test-if-a-function-is-called-from-within-another-function). It seems that the function being tested (`bar`) needs to be call with the same reference as the function that is being spyOn (`src.bar`). You need to refer inside `foo` to `src.bar`, so you'll have to use `this.bar`.