# Check if a function called another function in Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Consider the following Jasmine code I am running through Karma:

```
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    getName() { this.getFullName() }
    getFullName() { this.firstName + this.lastName }
}

describe('Test Person', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        const programmer = new Person('John', 'Gray');
        spyOn(programmer, 'getFullName');
        programmer.getName();
    });

    it('getName should call getFullName', () => {
        expect(programmer.getFullName).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
});
```

I want to check that `programmer.getName` did actually call `programmer.getFullName`. I know this can be tested here by checking the return value of `getName`, but I want to explicitly check if `getFullName` was called as this is the scenario in the actual code I am working with. I have implemented my code like shown above, but it's not working. Where am I going wrong?

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822947/angularjs-how-to-test-if-a-function-is-called-from-within-another-function) post, but it's not working here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move the `programmer` variable above in the `describe` block. Also, I suggest calling `getName()` it the test iteslf. This should work:

```
let programmer;
beforeEach(() => {
    programmer = new Person('John', 'Gray');
    spyOn(programmer, 'getFullName');
});

it('getName should call getFullName', () => {
    programmer.getName();
    expect(programmer.getFullName).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. The errors says 'Expected spy getFullName to have been called'.

Comment: It was actually due to async code, so my spec was executing before completion of the async code. My original code was correct otherwise :) But thanks for answering!

Comment: So what is the correct code after all?